# How to make background position doesn't change in a responsive website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, css-position

The issue I have is that when the size of the window changes the position of the background change as well and I want it to stay in the same position, I have this background on the body of the page.

Like this:

```
<body id="bg">

 <p>some text here</p>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#bg{
background-image:url(../../images/img1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: 25% 25%;
}
```

This is how it looks like when is on the default screen size:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2n03dsg.jpg]

And this is when the size screen change:

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/11tlpwz.jpg]

What I want to know is this:  Do I need to use media queries for this or is there a less complicated way to do it?

Comment: Try to change the position property to "fixed".

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fit the screen you should better use `background-size: cover;`.

Try this way:

```
#bg {
    background: url(../../images/img1.jpg) no-repeat 25% 25% fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Let me know if it'll do the trick ;-)

Comment: thanks, I already tried your code but the problem is that when the position: fixed when I scroll down the image moves with the content and I want to stay static and in an specific place of the body.

Comment: Try to just remove that `fixed` part then. The magic is done by `background-size: cover;` :)

Comment: this is what happens when I use background-size: cover; http://i60.tinypic.com/2ji0xv.jpg, and I need background-size: 100% auto; because is responsive, the problem is the position of the background.

Comment: Try with both `width:100%;` and `min-height:100%;`, in second step try to set those to the container too(even if it's `body`)

Comment: I already tried that but it remains the same, when screen size change background moves, I guess I'll have to use media queries :/

Comment: Yep, I think the same.